# power series expansion of the Confluent Hypergeometric Function

Tags: power-series, orthogonal-polynomials, hypergeometric-function

What is the power series expansion of the Confluent Hypergeometric Function of the Second Kind given by $U(a,b,x)$ ? what is the derivative of this function with respect to x.

Comment: The hypergeometric series may be found [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) together with its derivative

Comment: I want a series solution.Something like summation. @Nicco

Answer (score 1):

Since:
$$ U(a,b,x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-xt}t^{a-1}(1+t)^{b-a-1}\,dt\tag{1}$$
we have:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \frac{d}{dx}U(a,b,x) &=& -\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-xt}t^{a}(1+t)^{b-a-1}\,dt\\&=& -a\cdot U(a+1,b+1,x).\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please give me the series of the function.?

Comment: @Anu: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheSecondKind.html

Comment: I want an explicit form. something like summation from zero to n kind.

Comment: @Anu: do you know how hypergeometric functions are defined? If so, the linked page clearly gives a representation of $U$ in terms of hypergeometric functions.

Comment: @Anu:Hypergeometric series is summation ,isn't it